# Calculating Specific Catchment Area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, area, saga, catchment

I have tried to calculate the Specific Catchment Area in QGis from Specific Catchment Area and Flow Width Tool available through Saga. However, I got just SCA product with valour 0. I got a reasonable product with Flow width.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you provide more details about the precise steps that you performed, then your question is more likely to attract a potential answerer from amongst our volunteers.

Comment: Eduardo's description is precise. Because this tool is so simple, believe me, there is nothing much to add. If you give DEM then it will return `Flow width`. If you give DEM + Catchment Area, it will return `Flow width` + `SCA`.

Comment: Thank you Kazuhito, I got some results, however, I am not sure which file I should use in Total Catchment Area. I have read some discussion I saw that Total Catchment Area could be provided through Catchment Area or Flow Accumulation (through Saga tools available in Qgis). Initially, I thought that it was the catchment area rasterized (filled polygon or only the limit of catchment).  Please if anyone may give details about what is the file associated with Total Catchment Area.

Comment: Sorry Eduardo it seems I have missed your message. Yes, you are right; A raster layer Catchment area (aka Flow accumulation) is the one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flow width and Specific catchment area** tool in QGIS processing toolbox returns only `Flow width` if you do not give it a *Total Catchment Area (TCA)* layer as an input.

It is possibly misleading that the tool still produces a blank layer (all zeros), and I can understand your dismay at it.